# Getting error calling ShowViewModel

Tags: mvvmcross

Writing a sample app where I have a list of items, and then when the user clicks on a item - it uses ShowViewModel to display a detail page about the item. However, when call the method that calls ShowViewModel it crashes with the following error:
"Could not resolve type with token 01000037 
(from typeref, class/assembly MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxRequestedBy..."

The code for the sample app is here:
https://github.com/gregmercer/FruitsAndVeggies

The full error message is here:
https://github.com/gregmercer/FruitsAndVeggies/blob/master/error.txt

And the line that cause the error (when uncommented) is found here:
https://github.com/gregmercer/FruitsAndVeggies/blob/master/FruitsAndVeggies.Core/ViewModels/FruitsViewModel.cs#L58

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing MvvmCross versions.

So if you look at your packages.config for your core:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="MvvmCross" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.Binding" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.Core" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.Platform" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
</packages>
```

These are version 4.4.0

Then if we look at the Droid project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="MvvmCross" version="5.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.Binding" version="5.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.Core" version="5.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.Droid.Shared" version="5.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.Droid.Support.Core.UI" version="5.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.Droid.Support.Fragment" version="5.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat" version="5.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView" version="5.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.Platform" version="5.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Build.Download" version="0.4.3" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
</packages>
```

These are version 5.0.2, which is newer than 4.4.0.

Consolidate your packages and use same versions across all your projects.

Comment: Changing them to all use version 5.0.2 worked. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score -1):

To pass parameters you either need to inherit from a generic `MvxViewModel< Parameters>` or update to MvvmCross 5.0 which has improved support for passing objects without trouble.

Look at this sample as a reference: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/TestProjects/Navigation

Comment: Parameters _are_ supported in `ShowViewModel` using generics or not. This is clearly not the answer.

Comment: Parameters using an object are not supported if you don't set the generic type. If it is a primitive type you can, but that is not the case.

Comment: you can do `ShowViewModel<DerpVM>(new { hello = "World", herp = "derp" })` and get it in init: `public void Init(string hello, string herp)`. This has always worked.

Comment: Non-anonymous classes are also supported as always. There are _some_ limitations though. However, this doesn't answer OP's question and we should not discuss it here.